# Bash script which adds space inside long words in Pages file

Tags: bash

I like to convert documents to EPUB format because it is easier for me to read. However, if I do this for for example some code documentation, some really long lines of code are not readable in the EPUB, because they trail off-screen. I would like to automatically insert spaces in any words in a text file (specifically, a Pages document) over a certain length, so they are reduced to say, 10 character words, at maximum. Then, I will convert that Pages document to an EPUB.

How can I write a bash script which goes through a Pages document and inserts spaces into any word longer than, perhaps, 10 characters?

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is your friend:

```
$ cat input.txt
a file with a
verylongwordinit to test with.
$ sed 's/[^[:space:]]\{10\}/& /g' input.txt
a file with a
verylongwo rdinit to test with.
```

For every sequence of 10 non-whitespace characters in each line, add a space after (The `&` in the replacement text is itself replaced with the matched text).

If you want to change the file inline instead of making a copy, `ed` comes into play:

```
ed input.txt <<'EOF'
s/[^[:space:]]\{10\}/& /g
w
EOF
```

(Or some versions of `sed` take an `-i` switch for inline editing)

Comment: Did a bit of research, and assuming Pages is the Apple word processor, its file format is not plain text, and this obviously won't work. It might give you some idea of how to do it in Pages, though, assuming it supports regexp search and replace. (The RE dialect will likely be different from POSIX BRE, of course.)